# Building simple Objective-C example with clang on Ubuntu (linking fails)?

Tags: objective-c, linux, linker, clang

I'm trying to understand how Objective-C works, and the simplest example I found so far is from https://codeseekah.com/2012/09/12/compiling-objective-c-without-a-gui/ ; unfortunately, I cannot quite get it to compile (actually, link).

First of all, I use Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), and here I've installed:

```bash
sudo apt-get install clang-3.5 libobjc-4.8-dev
```

Then, I have the (slightly modified) files from the referenced page in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc0b573ae8ef2424aaeb043a6014b7fd), so you can just do:

```bash
cd /tmp
git clone https://gist.github.com/dc0b573ae8ef2424aaeb043a6014b7fd.git testobjc
cd testobjc
make
```

The `Makefile` there is modified to use the currently installed `clang-3.5`.

The first problem I had, was:

```
main.m:45:26: error: class method '+new' not found (return type defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]
  Person *brad = [Person new];
```

I found [Unable to compile Objective-C code on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038430/unable-to-compile-objective-c-code-on-ubuntu) :

> +(id)new is a function of the NSObject class. However, you are subclassing a runtime Object. To use most of the Apple methods you're used to using in OS X, you'll need to subclass NSObject instead.
>   You can still use the Foundation framework while using the GNU runtime. It should be available. There is a reference you can use here: blog.lyxite.com/2008/01/…

That last is a dead link, but copy on http://www.cnblogs.com/jack204/archive/2012/03/21/2410095.html :

> To Compile Objective-C Programs on Linux, GNUstep needs to be installed

Then I found [How to instantiate a class in Objective-C that don't inherit from NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954075/how-to-instantiate-a-class-in-objective-c-that-dont-inherit-from-nsobject) :

> You absolutely can do so. Your class simply needs to implement +alloc itself, the way that NSObject does. At base, this just means using malloc() to grab a chunk of memory big enough to fit the structure defining an instance of your class.

So this is what I don't get:

- If GNUstep provides Foundation Objective-C framework on GNU/Linux, then what is the role of `libobjc`?!

Since none of these `zoneAlloc` functions (needed for `init`/`alloc`) etc are available with the install of the above two packages, I did `grep -r " id" //usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/objc`, and found there is a function `class_createInstance` that returns an `id`, and so by defining a `new` method that uses it, the compiler does not generate error messages in the compilation step anymore.

But then, it fails in the linking step - the full build log is also in the gist (as `make.log`) - with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lobjc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Well, first of all, `libobjc.so` is in the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 May  7  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc_gc.so.4 -> libobjc_gc.so.4.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 267552 May  7  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc_gc.so.4.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 May  7  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc.so.4 -> libobjc.so.4.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112536 May  7  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc.so.4.0.0
```

... and in the Makefile, I've tried running the `clang` command by setting both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` - *and* I've also specified it with the "additional library paths" switch `-L` (in `LDFLAGS`). *All* of this seems to be ignored by the time the linker command `"/usr/bin/ld"` runs, but that doesn't matter, because the linker command itself has this in its arguments:

```
... -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu ...
```

... and this path does indeed expand to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (checked it with `readlink -f`), which is where `libobjc.so.*` are. But still the linker command fails ?!

So my second question is:

- Why doesn't `ld` find `libobjc.so.*`, even if `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` where it is located is specified on its command line arguments via `-L` -- and what do I need to do, to get this program to link?

Comment: I could expect a closevote for this question for many reasons, but definitely not for "off-topic"? Can someone explain how come this is off topic, and where can I post it instead (if there is such a site on Stack Exchange?) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well, turns out the linking stage can be solved with a symlink; I first tried to test with `ld`, and at first I was getting:

```
$ ld -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lobjc
ld: cannot find -lobjc
```

... however, with an explicit path, then `ld` does not complain about "cannot find" anymore:

```
$ ld -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc.so.4
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

So, when I looked at the directory more closely:

```
$ (cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu; ls libobjc*)
libobjc_gc.so.4  libobjc_gc.so.4.0.0  libobjc.so.4  libobjc.so.4.0.0
```

... it turns out, there are no files called simply `libobjc.so` - they all have names like `libobjc.so.*`... So I thought, maybe I should maybe a symlink with a name of `libobjc.so`:

```bash
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -s libobjc.so.4.0.0 libobjc.so
```

... and now when I run `make` - it actually succeeds! I get an executable file called `main`, and it runs fine:

```
$ ./main 
Hello, my name is Brad Cox!
Hello, my name is Tom Love!
```

Well, nice to have that sorted...